# Solve recurrence for strings that do not contain the substring 101

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Let's say $A_n$ is the number of binary string that has length $n$ and does not contain the substring 101. Calculate $A_n$ for $n=1,2\cdots8.$ Find a recurrence relation for $A_n$. What does the solution of that recurrence look like?

These are the solutions that I have found for calculations for $A_n$. $1, 4, 7, 12, 20, 32, 48, 96$.

I've calculated this by hand. But how I do find the recurrence? I see that 4, 7, 12, 30 are Fibonacci - 1, but not after or before that.

But I'm not sure how to do this or if this is even correct.

Comment: I think your values may be counting the complement; those strings that DO contain $101$, no?

Comment: Many similar questions have been asked on the site...[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818572/counting-the-number-of-bit-strings-containing-a-substring) for instance.

Comment: You should double check your values of $A_n$, they are all wrong. A hint: if you are having trouble getting a recurrence, let $B_n$ be strings avoiding 101 which end in 0, an let $C_n$ be strong avoiding 101 ending in 1, then get a mutual recurrence for those.

Comment: Thank you. I've edited my question to add the correct solution, but I'm still not sure how to find and solve the recurrence?

Comment: Try to proceed similarly to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2819720/71850) answer.

Comment: Is 2, 4, 5, 12, 20, 32,, 48, 64 correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> We count the number $a(n)$ of valid binary strings, i.e. strings which do not contain $101$   by *partitioning*  them according to their matching length with the initial parts of   the  *bad* string $101$.
>
> \begin{align*}
> a_n=a^{[\emptyset]}_n+a^{[1]}_n+a^{[01]}_n\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> - The  number $a^{[\emptyset]}_n$ counts the valid strings of  length  $n$   which do not start with the   rightmost character  of  the       bad   word $10\color{blue}{1}$,  i.e.  start  with $0$.
> - The  number $a^{[1]}_n$ counts the valid strings of length  $n$  which *do*  start with the   rightmost character  of  the       bad   word $10\color{blue}{1}$,  i.e.  $\color{blue}{1}$.
> - The  number $a^{[01]}_n$ counts the valid strings of length   $n$   which do  start with the two  rightmost characters  of  the       bad   word $1\color{blue}{01}$,  i.e. start  with   $\color{blue}{01}$.

We  get a    relationship  between valid strings of length $n$  with  those of length  $n+1$  as follows:

- If a word counted  by $a^{[\emptyset]}_n$ is appended by $0$ from the left it contributes to $a^{[\emptyset]}_{n+1}$. If it is appended by $1$ from the left it contributes to $a^{[1]}_{n+1}$.
- If a word counted  by $a^{[1]}_n$ is appended by $0$ from the left it contributes to $a^{[01]}_{n+1}$. If it is appended by $1$ from the left it contributes to $a^{[1]}_{n+1}$.
- If a word counted  by $a^{[01]}_n$ is appended by $0$ from the left it contributes to $a^{[\emptyset]}_{n+1}$. Appending from the left by $1$  is not allowed since then we have an invalid string starting with $101$.

> This relationship can be written as
>   \begin{align*}
> a^{[\emptyset]}_{n+1}&=a^{[\emptyset]}_{n}+a^{[01]}_{n}\tag{2}\\
> a^{[1]}_{n+1}&=a^{[\emptyset]}_{n}+a^{[1]}_n\tag{3}\\
> a^{[01]}_{n+1}&=a^{[1]}_n\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

We can  now derive a recurrence relation from (1) - (4):

> We obtain for $n\geq 3$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{a_{n+1}}&=a^{[\emptyset]}_{n+1}+a^{[1]}_{n+1}+a^{[01]}_{n+1}\tag{$ \to (1)$}\\
> &=\left(a^{[\emptyset]}_{n}+a^{[01]}_{n}\right)+\left(a^{[\emptyset]}_{n}+a^{[1]}_n\right)+\left(a^{[1]}_n\right)\tag{$\to (2),(3),(4)$}\\
> &=2a_n-a^{[01]}_{n}\tag{$\to (1)$}\\
> &=2a_n-a^{[1]}_{n-1}\tag{$\to  (4)$}\\
> &=2a_n-a_{n-2}+a^{[\emptyset]}_{n-2}+a^{[01]}_{n-2}\tag{$\to  (1)$}\\
> &=2a_n-a_{n-2}+a^{[\emptyset]}_{n-3}+a^{[01]}_{n-3}+a^{[1]}_{n-3}\tag{$\to  (2),(4)$}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2a_n-a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}}\tag{$\to (1)$}
> \end{align*}
>
> We  finally derive  manually the starting values
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{a_0=1,a_1=2,a_2=4,a_3=7}
> \end{align*}
>
> and     obtain a      sequence   $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$  starting with
>   \begin{align*}
> (a_n)_{n\geq 0}=(1,2,4,7,12,21,37,65,114,200,351,\ldots)
> \end{align*}

*Hint:*  We have $a_5=\color{blue}{21}$ valid strings of length $5$.  The    $2^5-21=11$ invalid strings are
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{101}00\qquad0\color{blue}{101}0\qquad00\color{blue}{101}\\
\color{blue}{101}01\qquad0\color{blue}{101}1\qquad01\color{blue}{101}\\
\color{blue}{101}10\qquad1\color{blue}{101}0\qquad\color{lightgrey}{10101}\\
\color{blue}{101}11\qquad1\color{blue}{101}1\qquad11\color{blue}{101}
\end{align*}

Comment: +1 Your answers (not just this one) are so good and clear, there needs to be a SUBSCRIBE button.  :)

Comment: @antkam: Many thanks for your nice comment. It's good to see the answer is useful. :-)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer This is very beautiful answer +1. I want to ask something. I asked a similar question today such that https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4096861/finding-recurrence-relation-that-contain-and-do-not-contain-122-in-the-alphabe. When i want to solve this question with my way in part $a-)$ , it seems that my solution is wrong because i found that it must be $a_n=2a_{n-1}-a_{n-3}$ but it break down for $n>4$. If you have free time ,can you look at my question in the link and say that why my solution is wrong ? I really wonder it because it works in my question but does not  this

Comment: Shouldn't the definition of $a_n^{[\emptyset]}$ be valid strings that do not start with $1$ or $01$, ie start with $00$? (And similarly $a_n^{[1]}$ be valid strings that start with $1$ but not with $01$, but this is equivalent to just starting with $1$.)

Comment: @ronno: You might want to check the derivation of $a_{n+1}$ for $n\geq 3$. It looks sound to me.

Comment: It seems to me that all of the derivation works with the definition I wrote. In particular, if you want to partition the valid strings into three classes, they should be disjoint. As written, it seems that the set of strings counted by $a_n^{[01]}$ is a subset of those counted by $a_n^{[\emptyset]}$.

Comment: @epi163sqrt hi Mr Markus it seems all your answer in combinatorics very intuitive could u suggest me a book in recursion/recurrence

Comment: @Will: You might find *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388254/recurrence-relations-book/4199500#4199500)* helpful. Kind regards,

Comment: thanks Mr Markus @epi163sqrt i appreciate your help a lot